# Can I have an unsigned AutoField?

Tags: django, django-models

I want a primary key for my model to be unsigned. Therefore I do something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

This gets me an `UNSIGNED` column in the resulting MySQL table, which I want. However, I believe I will not get the automatic assigning to `id` each time I create a new object, will I? This seems to require the use of `AutoField` instead. Problem is, `AutoField` is signed. Is there a way to create an unsigned `AutoField`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual type of the field is specified in the backend. In the case of MySQL, the backend is `django.db.backends.mysql`. This extract from `django/db/backends/mysql/creation.py` shows this translation:

```
class DatabaseCreation(BaseDatabaseCreation):
    # This dictionary maps Field objects to their associated MySQL column
    # types, as strings. Column-type strings can contain format strings; they'll
    # be interpolated against the values of Field.__dict__ before being output.
    # If a column type is set to None, it won't be included in the output.
    data_types = {
        'AutoField':         'integer AUTO_INCREMENT',
        'BooleanField':      'bool',
        'CharField':         'varchar(%(max_length)s)',
        ...
```

To change that, you should either monkey-patch this dict doing:

```
from django.db.backends.mysql.creation import DatabaseCreation
DatabaseCreation.data_types['AutoField'] = 'integer UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT'
```

Or you create your own class, so you won't mess up with the other `AutoFields`:

```
from django.db.models.fields import AutoField
class UnsignedAutoField(AutoField):
    def get_internal_type(self):
        return 'UnsignedAutoField'

from django.db.backends.mysql.creation import DatabaseCreation
DatabaseCreation.data_types['UnsignedAutoField'] = 'integer UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT'
```

And then create your own PKs:

```
id = UnsignedAutoField()
```

As it descends from `AutoField`, it will inherit all of its behavior.

Comment: This is not valid in more recent versions of Django ORM. `data_types` is no longer a property on `DatabaseCreation`. The good news is that `BigAutoField` is now in Django 1.10: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Just to be clear, neither of the solutions written by myself or Simanas should be used in real world projects. I wrote this as an example in which direction should one go if they'd decided to avoid DBMS built-in way, and not as a completed model ready to be used.**

I am sorry for writing an answer instead of a comment on the post made by Simanas, but I do not have high reputation to post one, and I feel it's needed as this question is pretty high ranked on 'django autofield unsigned integer' keywords.

Using his method is not reliable as it will produce an existing integer for new row if one of the previous objects gets deleted. Here's a modified one:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError
import re

class MyModel(models.Model):

    def next_id():
        try:
            # Find the ID of the last object
            last_row = MyModel.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
            return last_row.id + 1
        except IndexError:
            # No objects exist in database so far
            return 1

    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, default=next_id)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            try:
                super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
                break
            except IntegrityError, e:
                if e.args[0] == 1062:
                    if re.match("^Duplicate entry \'.*\' for key \'%s\'$"
                            % re.escape(self._meta.pk.name), e.args[1]):
                        self.id = next_id()
                    else:
                        raise
```

While this would work, it wouldn't know whether newly assigned ID was previously used for another objects (in case of deletion of newest objects?) and may lead to collisions in such cases; but it will work cross-database compared to Augusto's answer, which is MySQL specific.

Another caveat to this method is that if you have another application hooking to the same database, it'll have to provide the ID on INSERTs, as auto incremental is not done at database level.

You almost certainly don't want to do it this way.

Comment: As the response of @Simanas, this approach could suffer from concurrency issues. Egg, mutual exclusion http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion

Comment: Appreciate the reply @renan-ivo, I never thought of that at the time of writing. I've edited it to try counter the problem, even tho I wouldn't use it. Also added a comment on it.